# Accessing model attributes within a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, rake-task

I was wondering how to access a  Models attributes and then run in a rake task using some methods, from what i have read methods have to be declared outside of the task, but gaining access to the model is throwing me

I know that if i put this

```
namespace :grab do
 task :scores => :environment do
  puts User.all.inspect
 end
end
```

I would then have all the users printed

Below is what I am trying to achieve

**Rake Task**

```
namespace :grab do
 task :scores => :environment do
  points_total
  allocate_points
 end
end

def points_total
 wrong_predictions = [Prediction.home_score - Result.home_score, Prediction.away_score - Result.away_score]
 wrong_predictions = wrong_predictions.reject { |i| i == 0 }.size # returns 0, 1 or 2
  case wrong_predictions
   when 0 then 3
   when 1 then 1
   else 0
  end
end


 def allocate_points
  Prediction.update_attributes!(score: points_total)

 end
```

So i need access to my Prediction and Result model to perform these methods...

Any help appreciated

Thanks

EDIT

ok so running the task as it is above gives me the following error

```
 rake aborted!
 undefined method `home_score' for #<Class:0x4b651c0>
```

also to update here are my models

```
class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_score, :away_team, :fixture_id, :home_score, :home_team, :score

  has_one :fixture
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_score, :away_team, :fixture_date, :home_score, :home_team
end
```

Comment: You can access your Model(s) from your rake task, but what you are trying to do in points_total method is accessing two instances (prediction and result, not Prediction and Result); you should call the points_total method with this two instances: `points_total my_prediction, my_result`

Comment: Hi Galen, ok so firstly i need to use Result as opposed to result and secondly call method with these two instances? im not sure i follow, would you mind elaborating please, I have changed the instances errors

Comment: Sorry I cannot see very well why are you using class methods. Could you please share the models code?

Comment: hi, i have updated with my models..

Comment: Can you please tell how are you triggering the task?

Comment: in the console i am running %x[rake grab:scores], im using the console to see what is happening

Comment: @Richlewis I have post an Answer please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of being a rake task but because of the methods themselves.

Both your **Prediction** and **Result** models have a `home_score` method, but they are instance methods and not class methods as you are trying to use them in your `points_total` and `allocate_points` methods.

The difference between a class and an instance method is the object in which the method is called:

- Class method: is called on the Model itself, as in `User.new`. The `new` method is called on the `User` model to generate a new instance of the Model.
- Instance method: is callen on a specific instance of a model, as in `my_user.name = "Terminator"`. The `name` method is called on the specific `my_user` User to change its (and just its) name.

Looking at your code, your methods home_score are thought to be applied on specific instances of predictions and results, as they are instance methods. This is the error that the console is throwing, the methods are not available for the Class (the Model).

Assuming your rake task is trying to update the total points of each Prediction in your database, the code would be:

lib/tasks/grab.rake

```
namespace :grab do
 task :scores => :environment do
  Prediction.all.each do |prediction|
    score = points_total prediction, prediction.result
    allocate_points prediction, score
  end
 end
end

def points_total prediction, result
 wrong_predictions = [prediction.home_score - result.home_score, prediction.away_score - result.away_score]
 wrong_predictions = wrong_predictions.reject { |i| i == 0 }.size # returns 0, 1 or 2
  case wrong_predictions
   when 0 then 3
   when 1 then 1
   else 0
  end
end

 def allocate_points prediction, score
  prediction.update_attributes!(score: score)
 end
```

However, that is a kind of 'pseudo-code' because some relation between Prediction and Result models should exist in order to use them as in points_total method. My code is assuming a has_one association, which sould be also reflected in the models; but as I do not know exactly the whole picture for your app I did not want to change this, just focusing on the rake methods.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you for a very in depth answer, will read over a few times to grasp understanding, as for the rake task itself i am getting a duplicated argument def points_total(prediction, prediction.result)...with regards to relationships a prediction has_one result with the prediction_id as a FK in the result model

Comment: Yes, regarding the relationship that has_one was what I assumed in the answer. Regarding the error, not sure to understand; the method points_total is called with two different parameters: a prediction (Prediction instance) and its result (prediction.result, a Result instance), they are different objects. Could you please post the exact error thrown?

Comment: scoring_system_logic/lib/tasks/retrieve_score.rake:10: duplicated argument name
def points_total prediction, prediction.result
                                        ^
/scoring_system_logic/lib/tasks/retrieve_score.rake:10: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ';' or '\n'
def points_total prediction, prediction.result
                                        ^
C:/Sites/scoring_system_logic/lib/tasks/retrieve_score.rake:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
scoring_system_logic/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
=> ""

Comment: Sorry @Richlewis, it was my fault. I have edited the code in the answer, now it should work

Comment: no need to apologise, your helping me remember.... ok so when i run the task i get the  error undefined method `home_score' for nil:NilClass..however i have just noticed my result doesnt have a prediction_id in its attributes, so will add now and see if makes a difference

Comment: It should, remember also to define the has_one association in the models

Comment: hi @galen, i was just wondering how this would work with a has_many relationship, the result.home_score is no longer correct is it? i have changed my relationship and i am getting undefined method result for Prediction...any help appreciated